# Dojo store query with wildcard

Tags: dojo

I'm using a Dojo memory store (dojo/store/Memory).  I would like to retrieve items based on a wildcard query but the query method doesn't seem to support wildcards.  i.e. given the following items:

```
{ id: "apple", details: "fruit" }
{ id: "applemac", details: "computer" }
```

`store.query({ id: "apple" })` returns the first row as expected, but `store.query({ id: "apple*" })` returns nothing.

Does anyone know if it's possible to use wildcards and if so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `RegExp` object to do wildcard queries

```
store.query({id:new RegExp("apple*")})
```

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shoe788/RZqHQ/3/)